# Attributes of extended - traditional inheritance - odoo module not created in the database

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

I extended the '**res.partner**' *odoo module* with the following code

`class ResPartner(models.Model):
    _name = 'res.partner'
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    sales_force_ids = fields.One2many('sales_calc.sales_calc')
    ake_code = fields.Char('AKE Code')`

I restarted Odoo server nut when I'm trying to go to the module in **apps** to upgrade the module, the **apps** page is displayed as **white screen**

In odoo log the following error is found.

> ProgrammingError: column res_partner.ake_code does not exist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **problem not** in the **inheritance mechanism** but **upgrading** module only is **not enough**, I had to **uninstall and install module again**.

I commented `ake_code = fields.Char('AKE Code')`, **restarted odoo** server,  **uninstalled the module**, **uncommented** `ake_code = fields.Char('AKE Code')`,  **restarted odoo** server and Finally **installed** the module **again**.

I was **confused** by **another** raised **warning** while installing the module again:

> There is no reference field 'None' found for 'sales_calc.sales_calc'

The problem is related to `sales_force_ids = fields.One2many('sales_calc.sales_calc')` I had to write the **related field** `id` as `sales_force_ids = fields.One2many('sales_calc.sales_calc', 'id')` to install the module normally without this warning.

Comment: The root problem was you specifying `_name = 'res.partner'` if you're just extending an Odoo model, you don't need to specify the name again `_inherit = 'res.partner'` is enough

Comment: **No, This is not problem at all**, it is **optiona**l parameter, I know it is **not important** to be written in case of **extending a module**. Actually it **was not written** at first while the **problem was existing** and it is **still written** while **problem is solved** according to the written **answer above**. **Note**: I regenerated the problem and solved it more than once to be sure of the answer. Thanks @danidee.

Comment: @danidee See it in odoo documentation **class inheritance**,  It is written in the **figure** of **Inheritance title** `_name = 'obj1'` and it is different than the **prototyping inheritance** `_name = 'new'` although the two types of inheritance have `_inherit = obj1`.  `https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/howtos/backend.html`

Comment: Changing `res.partner` will always carry this problems. Just start your server with `--update=my_modul` parameter to force an immediate update on your custom module. That should solve the problem.

Comment: @CZoellner Thanks, I'm going to try that